# Deleting system font files in OS Catalina

Tags: macos, fonts, macos-catalina

I'm trying to get rid of the huge list of superfluous fonts that come with OS Catalina. I disabled SIP but still don't get the option to move files on system/library/fonts to the bin. Somehow they're still protected.

Thanks for the help, cheers

Comment: The entire system partition is read only on Catalina.

Comment: I found this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372000/85275 - can't test it, no Mac here capable of Catalina… all now-abandoned Mac Pros :\

Comment: Excellent - do you want to post as an answer, for future searchers?

Comment: Solved. In case anyone needs to know this are the steps: Disable SIP in recovery mode, enable root user and log on, run sudo mount -uw / on terminal. This command enables write access until the next restart. Thanks @Tetsujin

Answer (score 0):

Boot up from a cloned OS (Mojave) on external SSD. YOU can then have access to the partition where those system fonts are stored and will be able to delete whatever you wish.

You'll see 2 partitions on your boot drive. Look for the one that has system/library/fonts folder

On another note, I am trying to figure out how to modify the system font as with previous OS releases. Was able to use fontlab to open the system font file, and replace the glyphs, export to a ttf and then replace the SFNS.ttf file and the system display font changed no problem. Does not work with Catalina, as all I get is a flashing screen. Anyone have thoughts?